# How to retrieve cached version of Style.css

Tags: css, backup

I accidently overwrote my stylesheet and need help to find a backup

Comment: What are you talking about? Where do you think it's cached?

Comment: @slaks I was thinking it could be in one of my browsers. I was wondering if anyone knows how I could retrieve this file that I ftp'd over

Comment: The cache of a web browser is not a reliable backup plan :)

Comment: @thirtydot yeah thats what I just figured out :/ Is there any way to find it besides that

Comment: Based on the browser you have to retrieve it from different places (assuming its not overwritten)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox type "about:cache" in the adress bar, and click on the link to list all the cached files... if I discover how to do the same in other browsers I'll update my answer.

Good Luck meanwhile... and +1 for the "backup" tag! LOL :D

**Edit for Opera and Chrome**

http://www.techyard.net/view-opera-and-chrome-cache/

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post and i know this won't help the OP anymore, but i was searching for the same thing and found a talented guy who made a terrific and simple copy/paste (no kidding!) tool to recover a cached file!

http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2012/01/viewing-chrome-cache-easy-way.html

For anyone ever in need for such solutions, go there and follow the instructions, nothing so simple and helpful! saved me tons of hours of work!!!

And remember to thank this awesome guy! :D

Comment: ty partial life saver. Like an idiot after permanently deleting my working directory I refreshed my page which overwrote the html and css cache. Managed to recover most pages. Chrome chrome://cache/ is a life saver, tried grep'n in ~/.cache/chromium/Default/Cache but the files are gzipped (I think).

Answer (score -3):

Windows users:

**Right-click the file or folder, and then click Restore previous versions**